# Concerning Linear Algebra As A Prerequisite To Single Variable Calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

I hope that I can be forgiven. Both for my ignorance and for asking a question that has likely been answered already. I could not find the question myself. I was wondering about the study of linear algebra and limits before the study single variable calculus. I have not read the book, sadly, but to quote a section from Dieudonne's Foundations Of Modern Analysis Volume 1, Page 147.

*That presentation, which throughout
adheres strictly to our general “geometric” outlook on analysis, aims at
keeping as close as possible to the fundamental idea of calculus, namely the
“ local ” approximation of functions by linear functions. In the classical
teaching of calculus, this idea is immediately obscured by the accidental
fact that, on a one-dimensional vector space, there is a one-to-one
correspondence between linear forms and numbers, and therefore the derivative at a point is defined as a number instead of a linear form. This slavish
subservience to the shibboleth of numerical interpretation at any cost
becomes much worse when dealing with functions of several variables :
one thus arrives, for instance, at the classical formula (8.9.2) giving the
partial derivatives of a composite function, which has lost any trace of
intuitive meaning, whereas the natural statement of the theorem is of course
that the (total) derivative of a composite function is the composite of their
derivatives (8.2.1), a very sensible formulation when one thinks in terms of
linear approximations.*

Should linear algebra and limits be studied before looking at the derivative and integral of even calculus I. Again, I am sorry if this question was posed in a more clear way and I am sorry if it was already given a clear answer.

Comment: I would say: you definitely don’t have to, but I strongly recommend (interested in pure mathematics as I am) that you learn limits first. You can just learn formulae and **do** the calculus for the sake of engineering, physics or any application but if you want to really understand what you’re doing, definitely learn limits first. Linear algebra I’d say is not necessary until you do multivariable analysis

Comment: I'd say no, you don't have to learn linear algebra before single-variable calculus. Just keep in mind that the best way to think about the derivative is this: $f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)$. A nonlinear function $f$ (difficult) is approximated locally by a linear function (easy). The approximation is good when $x$ is close to $a$. Generalizing calculus to several variables motivates us to invent linear transformations and linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Dieudonné's book is an old, abstract, advanced take on calculus that is not, as far as I know, commonly read. I have never read it. That doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't read it, but in general, *no*, linear algebra is not a prerequisite for calculus.

However, I will mention it's probably good to broaden your perspective and learn some linear algebra as well as calculus, perhaps concurrently if you have the time to do so.

If you are interested in a high-level treatment of calculus then I will suggest that the first chapter of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher contains a nice somewhat panoramic view of "advanced" math. You might appreciate the added perspective this brings.

If you just want to learn how to differentiate and integrate and not worry about details, then forget about Amann and Escher and just find any one of the million resources on calculus and have at it.

Last bit of advice: Math people sometimes like to pretend that math is a linear subject, wherein it's mandatory to learn subject X before embarking upon subject Y, which uses subject X. This is only half true. Yes, foundations matter, but if you're *really interested* in subject Y, and you don't have a great grasp of subject X (which perhaps you find somewhat boring), then subject Y is a great way to motivate the study of subject X. When you study subject Y you'll be motivated to do so, and then when you find that you need some background from subject X you can go figure that out, and you know exactly why you're doing so, because you need it for subject Y. So don't necessarily be afraid to go back and forth.

Comment: Thank you all for the great feedback! I also never expected a response to happen so quickly. I wanted to leave an (upvote?), but my reputation is not high enough at this point. Every response was thorough and extremely helpful. Again, thank you everyone!

Comment: @UncreativeName I think you need 15 reputation to upvote. If you get to 15 reputation then you can upvote this answer and accept it. At any rate, happy to help.